# How to use the `ssh-add` session on `openssl pkeyutl -decrypt`

Tags: encryption, openssh, openssl

I converted my `id_rsa` private key to the RSA format using

```sh
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

explained in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/950686/218400).

I then added some handy aliases that will allow me to encrypt and decrypt data with my own identity files:

```sh
alias encrypt='openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 -pubin -inkey <(ssh-keygen -e -f "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" -m PKCS8)'
alias decrypt='openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 -inkey "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa"'
```

Now I can do:

```sh
echo foobar | encrypt > test.enc
cat test.enc | decrypt
```

It will print `foobar`, but the `test.enc` can be stored without exposing `foobar`. Surely there are better ways to do it, but the reason why I attempt to do it like this is to get rid of any password prompts.

My `id_rsa` is password protected, but I start my terminal session with `ssh-add` which prompts me for my password passphrase only once, so that when I use `ssh` (including `git`), I don't have to enter my passphrase again.

However, the same cannot be said for `openssl pkeyutl -decrypt`, it will ask for a password phrase whenever I use it, which makes sense, because `openssl` is the underlying tool used by `openssh`.

Regardless, is there any way to use the `ssh-add` session for `openssl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I converted my id_rsa private key to the RSA format using

You converted it to either PEM or PKCS#8 format. It was always an RSA key, only the encapsulation changed.

> Regardless, is there any way to use the ssh-add session for openssl?

No, there isn't. The ssh-agent doesn't provide access to the raw private key – it only provides the ability to do certain operations with it, much like the software equivalent of a smartcard or a Yubikey. Specifically, it provides a 'sign' operation but **not** a 'decrypt' operation.

(After all, its main purpose is to be used for SSHv2 – which doesn't really do any private-key decryption; signing is all it ever needs.)

You could possibly use GnuPG with its gpg-agent as an alternative – the 'gpg' tool primarily deals with PGP-format files, but it also comes with 'gpgsm' for the CMS format that's close to what OpenSSL produces.

---

But even if you wanted only signing, OpenSSL doesn't support using ssh-agent for that either. (No fundamental reason for that; it's simply not implemented. It would likely favor PKCS#11 as the interface; p11-kit + softhsm can be turned into a kind of "openssl-agent".

And if the situation doesn't specifically require a PKCS#7/CMS/SMIME format signature, there are alternatives – OpenSSH comes with its own signature format which you can find in 'ssh-keygen'; and it's pretty easy to write a custom Python tool that signs stuff through ssh-agent, using the 'paramiko' module.)

It is also usually not recommended to use the same key for different functions – even though it's technically possible for the same RSA key to be used for both signatures and encryption, cryptography experts often advise against doing so as a precaution.

Comment: That explains why is the file was called `id_rsa` to begin with. The algorithm is the same, just the encoding is different. I also agree that it's not recommend to share the same identity for different purposes for the same reason why password re-use should be prevented. This is just an attempt to have free API keys protected in a public dot file configuration. An abuse would at worse cause the key getting rate limited, nothing more. (Things like DeepL, etc.). I've heard from `pgp` to solve this problem and will consider it, but I was hoping I could get away with what I already have. Cheers.

Comment: For my use case I could use openssh to generate a signature which I then can use for a symmetrical encryption (ref: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/142487/103820). Since this is about personal storage instead of secure message transfer, it would be sufficient enough. Although, it might be better to go along an official route and botching my own. Accepted.